# unresolved overloaded function type for "fs::path::string"

Tags: c++, boost

boost 1.49
gcc version 4.6.3

```
        std::transform(barcodeFiles.begin(), barcodeFiles.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cerr, "\n"),
            boost::bind(&fs::path::string, _1));
```

How to edit this code ?

```
[ 65%] Building CXX object c++/lib/demultiplex/CMakeFiles/casava_demultiplex.dir/BclDemultiplexer.cpp.o
/bak/software/Linux/CASAVA_v1.8.2/src/c++/lib/demultiplex/BclDemultiplexer.cpp: In member function ‘const casava::demultiplex::BclDemultiplexer::ClusterCorrectedBarcodeIndex casava::demultiplex::BclDemultiplexer::mapClusterBarcodes(unsigned int) const’:
/bak/software/Linux/CASAVA_v1.8.2/src/c++/lib/demultiplex/BclDemultiplexer.cpp:65:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(, boost::arg&)’
/bak/software/Linux/CASAVA_v1.8.2/src/c++/lib/demultiplex/BclDemultiplexer.cpp:65:50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use C++11 (GCC 4.6 supports it using the flag -std=c++0x), then you can use a lambda function and it will become more readable:

```
std::transform(barcodeFiles.begin(), barcodeFiles.end(),
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cerr, "\n"),
               [](const fs::path& p) {
                   return p.string();
               }
);
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer can be found in the [FAQ of boost bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloaded)

```
std::transform(
    paths.begin(), paths.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(
        std::cerr, "\n"
    ),
    boost::bind(
        static_cast<
            std::string const & (boost::filesystem::path::*)() const
        >(&boost::filesystem::path::string), 
        _1
    )
);
```

Comment: Forgot a `&` at `static_cast<std::string const **&** (...` - I have added that now.